# How to install Tomcat server using no login shell

Tags: linux, administrator

How can we create a user account with no login shell for running the Tomcat server.

What is the purpose of User Account with no login shell ?

And How can no login shell user perform the installation of Tomcat Server using non-login user id ?

Comment: The [answer to this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/367502/how-to-change-tomcat-user-in-red-hat-linux) seems related.

Answer (score 2):

To create a system user account with no shell:

```
$ sudo useradd -r -m -d ${TOMCAT_HOME} -s /sbin/nologin tomcat
```

By setting the shell to */sbin/nologin* it is more difficult for the account to be accidentally comprimised (e.g., a password gets set for user tomcat and someone tries to login). It will also stop a shell from being created using `sudo su tomcat -`.

It is, however, still possible to run commands as this user with sudo:

```
$ sudo -u tomcat COMMAND
```

If using a package manager, be sure it doesn't already create a tomcat user for you. If extracting from an archive, ensure that the archive is in a location that is accessible by the tomcat user (e.g., */tmp*).

Comment: I am not clear on the lines start from " By setting the shell.." Can you Explain in full details

Comment: After the system allows a user to log in, a shell process is started. Typically a user shell is a program designed for interactive control (e.g., */bin/sh*) but it can be any executable. The [/sbin/nologin](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/8/nologin/) executable simply returns a message and exits, effectively logging the user session out. Setting */sbin/nologin* is a backstop in the event other login control mechanisms (e.g., allowed uid range, no empty password, etc.) are not working properly. Even if the system allows the user to log in, the shell immediately exits.

Comment: @Java_Linux_Buddy_112358 you run `chsh` as the user in question to change the login shell.

Comment: @terdon That's true, but you can only change the shell if the default login shell accepts commands - */sbin/nologin* does not.

Comment: @plasmid87 ah OK, I just tried and it won't let me switch to `/bin/false`. I guess you have to edit `/etc/passwd` directly then.

Answer (score 1):

1. By creating a normal user account with a shell which either doesn't exist or doesn't allow user to run any commands. E.g. shell might be `/bin/nologin` or `/bin/true`.
2. The idea is to give ownership of Tomcat files to a certain user instead of the super user, ie. 'root', so that when you run Tomcat you don't have to run that process as 'root'. For security, simply.
3. Most likely this is not possible. What I'd do is to create a normal user account, do the installation and then change the login shell of the said account to be something else than a working shell (see 1).